# Sort objects using Comparable<> . Error

Tags: java

It worked, but now I open my project and check the code and it does not work correctly;

This is my code:

```
  class House implements Comparable<House>
    {

    private String hName;
    private int windowsNumber,
                doorNumber;

    //...


    @Override
    public int compareTo(House obj)
    {

        int nr = ((House)obj).getWindowsNumber();

        return nr - getWindowsNumber();

    }
```

the main function looks like this:

```
 House[] arr = new House[3];

        House tent = new House("House",6,1);
        House  bigTent = new House("The biggest house",10,3);
        House  shouse = new House("Medium house",8,4);



        arr[0]= tent;
        arr[1]= bigTent;
        arr[2]= shouse;

        Arrays.sort(arr);

        int i = 0;
        for(House temp : arr)
            {

            System.out.println("Houses "+ ++i + " :"+temp.getHouseName()+" with windows: "+temp.getWindowsNumber());

            }
```

I am getting this error: `sortobject.House cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`. Can someone figure it out? I do not know what it is wrong with it..

FULL ERROR CODE:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: sortobject.House cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(ComparableTimSort.java:290)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:157)
    at java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort(ComparableTimSort.java:146)
    at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:472)
    at sortobject.SortObject.main(SortObject.java:24)
Java Result: 1
```

EDIT 2:

**I created a new project and wrote the code with the same approach like I did before, and it works. I believe that something was wrong with my Interface<>.**

Comment: Things look fine here.

Comment: FYI your `compareTo` method has redundant code. It should simply say `return obj.getWindowsNumber() - getWindowsNumber()`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, that cast is redundant.

Comment: Try `Arrays.<House>sort(...`?

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon it changed nothing

Comment: Most likely you are not building your project properly and you are using an old `class` file.  Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @Peter Lawrey IDE 7.3.1, NetBeans

Comment: I would make it do a clean build so you are using the latest code.

Answer (score 0):

With JDK 1.7 seems to be working properly - made a local copy of your code, compiled and executed main method successfully. Maybe, really, cleaning the project can magically help.

Comment: I think problem is in the different House class used, as @Nishant Shreshth wrote, not an IDE problem.

Comment: Maybe you are using a different `Comparable` interface? Change `Arrays.sort(arr);` to `Collections.sort(Arrays.<House>asList(arr));` and it will tell you at *compile time* if there’s something wrong.

Comment: Ok, I created a new project and wrote code again (not copy & paste), and it works.

Comment: @Holger it tells that I cannot do this like you wrote because this is not suitable method...

Comment: @Ernusc: the important point is the reason it tells you. It seems to confirm the suspicion that you have a different `Comparable` interface in your project.

Comment: Indeed, I believe this is a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might be referring to a different `House` in the main method (probably a class in another package which has the same structure except that it doesn't implement `Comparable`). Make sure this `House` is same as the `House` above:

`House[] arr = new House[3];`